# How to add data to React's props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to implement SSR with `react-frontload`. The author of the library has written a tutorial at https://hackernoon.com/react-frontload-3ff68988cca. So far, everything else has made sense, but I can't figure out what's happening in `getProfileAsync()` in the beginning of this example (taken from the above tutorial):

```
import { frontloadConnect } from 'react-frontload'

// assuming here that getProfileAsync returns a Promise that
// resolves when the profile is loaded into props.boundProfile
const frontload = (props) => (
  getProfileAsync(props.username)
)

// all available options, set to the default values
const options = {
  noServerRender: false,
  onMount: true,
  onUpdate: true
}

// just decorate the same underlying component from earlier
const ProfileView =
  frontloadConnect(frontload, options)((props) => (
    props.profile
      ? <div>{props.profile.fullName}'s profile</div>
      : <div>loading..</div>
  ))
```

Here's how I'm trying to implement this:

```
const frontload = props => (
  getPage('/home').then(page => props.page = page)
);

const ContentRoute =
  frontloadConnect(frontload)(props => (
    props.page
      ? <div>Content goes here</div>
      : <div>Loading...</div>
  ));

export default ContentRoute;
```

**What I don't get is how to pass `page` in `frontload()` to `props` in `frontloadConnect()`, which is what I suppose I should be doing.**

My `getPage()` returns a Promise by `axios`:

```
const getPage = route => axios
  .get('...query...')
  .then(res => res.data.data.pages[0]);
```

I suppose it's working correctly since `getPage('/home').then(page => console.log(page))` logs the object that I'm looking for.

Big thanks!

EDIT1: The error that I'm getting is: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot add property page, object is not extensible`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of `react-frontload`.

> What I don't get is how to pass page in frontload() to props in frontloadConnect()

You can't, at least not directly. Your frontload function should return a `Promise<void>` and should not modify (or mutate) `props` in any way - it doesn't 'pass on' props to the underlying component.

Instead, it should perform async request(s) and then update state using your state management solution of choice. This could be redux, or it could be as simple as a parent component with react component state. Of course, the state management code needs to be wrapped in a function which is passed as a prop further up the chain and is then accessible from the frontload function.

To illustrate with code, **here's your example using redux** (reducer etc left out to keep it short)

```
const mapState = (state) => ({
  page: state.page
})

const mapDispatch = (dispatch) => ({
  updatePage: () => (
    getPage('/home')
      .then(page => dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_PAGE', page }))
  )
})

const frontload = props => (
  // state update left to redux connected function 
  // which is added to props further up the chain
  // i.e. props are not directly modified in the frontload function
  props.updatePage() 
);

const ContentRoute =
  connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(
  frontloadConnect(frontload)(props => (
    props.page // page is connected from redux state
      ? <div>Content goes here</div>
      : <div>Loading...</div>
  )));

export default ContentRoute;
```

Why? Because this way `react-frontload` doesn't need to concern itself with asynchronous state/props management and can leave this to the state management solution you are already using.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to use comments here for thanks, but I'm making an exception this time. My mistake was to interpret "state management solution" as my API service. I have now gotten past a major point of noobiness and learned to use Redux along the way. Dave, I want to extend my warmest thanks to you, getting this to work was seriously a pretty big deal for me. I shall remain in your debt. (Also, whoever's reading this in the future, just take a moment to appreciate what a wonderful open-source system and community we have!)